# Go map[int]struct JSON Marshal

Tags: json, struct, go, marshalling

Trying to parse a map[int] to user defined struct in go:

Here are the data schemas.

```
type Recommendation struct {
    Book  int     `json:"book"`
    Score float64 `json:"score"`
}
```

Here is the json marshaling:

```
ureco := make(map[int]data.Recommendation)
ureco, _ = reco.UserRunner()

json, _ := json.Marshal(ureco)
fmt.Println(json)
```

Where reco.UserRunner() returns the appropriate struct type.

This prints an empty json object:

```
[]
```

UPDATE:

error message:

```
json: unsupported type: map[int]data.Recommendation
```

So how do I json a map of structs? or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to marshal it, you could just iterate over your map and turn it into a slice.

```
slc := make([]data.Recommendation)
for _, val := range ureco {     
    slc = append(out, val)
}
json, _ := json.Marshal(slc)
```

You can see a simple example with a `map[int]string` here: http://play.golang.org/